# Should a symbol be followed by a noun

Tags: mathematics, writing-style

Suppose one writes a scientific paper from Math or a related field. Should mathematical symbols be followed by nouns describing them? Should f, x, Ω, P(A) and ß be preceded by function, variable, set, probability and angle?

A rule, which I know, says that a symbol shouldn't start a sentence. Is it also wrong if it is inside a sentence? Does the same apply to the labels like Equation (2)? Is it correct to say **After solving (2) we get that x=2**? Or should I use **Equation (2)**?

I guess it's fine to omit a descriptional noun before a variable inside a logical relation like an equation, but is the same true for free variables?

Example 2: **For every event in Ω** or **For every event in the set Ω**?
Example 3: **The same is true for y and z** or **The same is true for variables y and z**?

---

Is there a rule of thumb about grammar? Like **function f** instead of **a function f**?

Comment: There's no shame in reading other papers (not all of the same author) and see how other people are writing. This way you should get a feel on how your field handles these things.

Comment: If I've made it clear once (or twice) that X is a set, I don't feel obligated to repeat "set" every time I mention X.

Comment: Avoid ambiguity, write for clarity.

Comment: I agree with @AndreasBlass, with one exception: I never begin a sentence with a mathematical symbol.  Also, "Equation (2) implies x=2."

Comment: Yes, I write 'for every x in the set \Omega...' too.  The primary reason is to help remind the reader what \Omega is.

Comment: This is about five separate questions in one...